# Android - GPS and Network Providers conflict

Tags: android, networking, gps, location

I'm creating app to listen to location changes, in `onResume()` I call these two methods:

```
_locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 10,locationListenerGps);
_locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 10, locationListenerNetwork);
```

When I do that, I never get location from `GPS_PROVIDER`, only from `NETWORK_PROVIDER`.

What more, when I get location from NETWORK and it gets to method `onStatusChanged()` (resulting in `TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE`) app is stucked and nothings going on. There are no location updates at all, until I restart app.

I'll be thankful for any help in discovering why it's not working like I thought it might...

Comment: Your post will be better with a clear question!

Comment: We need more information: logcat, gps detailed status etc.

Comment: You need to be outdoors to get a GPS signal.

Comment: What device are you testing this on?